# Set different cell widths of 3 tables

Tags: java, codenameone

I have 3 tables in the same form, but they have different no. of columns and I want to set different column width for each of the tables. Can I obtain that in the code below or I have to create 3 different classes extending table and then set different constraint width? By doing so I am writing same code thrice which I don't want to do.

```
protected void beforeReport(Form f){
  Table table=new MyTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNamesInOut,dataInOut));
  Table tablePunishment=new MyTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNamesPunishment,dataPunishment));
  Table tableAccident=new MyTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNamesAccident,dataAccident));
}

public class MyTable extends Table {

  public MyTable(TableModel tm) {
    super(tm, true);
  }

  public Component createCell(Object value, int row, int col, boolean editable) {
    Component component = null;
    if (value instanceof Vector) {
      Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      Iterator i = ((Vector) value).iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
        c.addComponent(new Label(i.next().toString()));
      }
      component = c;
    } else {
      component = super.createCell(value, row, col, editable);
    }
    return component;
  }

  @Override
  protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
    TableLayout.Constraint constraint = ((TableLayout) this.getLayout()).createConstraint();
    constraint.setVerticalAlign(CENTER);
    addComponent(constraint);

    switch (column) {
      case 0: {
        constraint.setWidthPercentage(25);
        break;
      }
      case 1: {
        constraint.setWidthPercentage(25);
        break;
      }
      case 2: {
        constraint.setWidthPercentage(25);
        break;
      }
      case 3: {
        constraint.setWidthPercentage(25);
        break;
      }
    }
    return constraint;
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you use column.setPreferredWidth() to specify table column widths?

Comment: no, since you've to be precise to use setPrefferedWidth but setWidthPercentage adjust the coln size in all different screens.

Comment: And most important thing, i think TableLayout.Constraint doesnt take setPrefferedWidth method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the columns to be identical in width you can do something like:

```
protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
   TableLayout.Constraint constraint = ((TableLayout) this.getLayout()).createConstraint();
   constraint.setVerticalAlign(CENTER);
   addComponent(constraint);
   constraint.setWidthPercentage(100 / getModel().getColumnCount());
   ...
 }
```

Otherwise you can just go with a new constructor something in the line of:

```
public class MyTable extends Table {
  private int[] widths;
  public MyTable(TableModel tm, int... widths) {
    super(tm, true);
    this.widths = widths;
  }
```

Then you can just do this in the createCell:

```
constraint.setWidthPercentage(widths[column]);
```

Comment: tysm... u saved  my day